# Delegates. Do they refer to instances of other delegates, or just methods?

Tags: c#, .net

This code in a loop creates instances of a delegate that refers to the previous instance of the delegate, each of which refers to a method, or is it just that new methods are added to the internal data structure of one instance of the delegate? How to understand this in debug windows - are instances or methods are simply added?
Memory grows very quickly and I'm trying to figure out how it works. Difference between many instances with two references (to a method and another instance) or one instance with a lot of re-references.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            void MyMethod() { }

            MyDelegate a = null;            

            while (true)
            {              
                a += MyMethod;                
            };
        }
    }

    delegate void MyDelegate();
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `var methods = a.GetInvocationList();`?

Comment: You're creating a [multicast delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/how-to-combine-delegates-multicast-delegates) that calls `MyMethod` multiple times. `a += MyMethod` is syntactic sugar for `a = (MyDelegate) Delegate.Combine(a, new MyDelegate(MyMethod));`.

Comment: What is the point in subscribing an infinite number of time the same `MyMethod` callback to this `a` event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither; it isn't a chain ("refers to the previous instance of the delegate"), and it isn't a change in the internal structure of a single delegate. The key here is that delegates are meant to be immutable, which would not work with either of those approaches - since consider:

- you have delegates A, B, C, D, E
- you create F = A+B+C+D+E
- now you do G = F-C
- it is still required that F covers A,B,C,D,E, and that G covers A,B,D,E

  - this would not be possible with a single chain, because: what happens between B=>C=>D vs B=>D
  - this would not be possible by mutating the internal state, because we'd need two conflicting states

So instead, *conceptually* you can think of a multi-cast delegate being an array of the delegates it spans. When you add/subtract, a *new completely different* delegate with a separate array (with more or fewer elements) is created.

This means that in your test, at each iteration you're allocating:

- a new delegate instance
- a new array of length (the old length plus one)

Even if we ignore the delegate instances themselves, the array sizes creates a telescoping series that gets big pretty quickly (`N * (N+1) / 2`, so: roughly `N^2`).

This isn't an *exact* description - just a conceptual one. You can view the contents of this inner array (conceptually) via `GetInvocationList()`